# Why does a range search ":[range]/pattern/action" not work the same way as ":[range]g/pattern/action"?

Tags: search, range

Can someone explain why range search `:[range]/pattern/action` does not work the same way as `:[range]g/pattern/action`?

Also `:'a,'b/pattern/action` gives a warning that the range is 'backward', even though `'a` is less than `'b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `:[range]/pattern/action`, the `/pattern/` part is actually *part* of the range.

See [`:help cmdline-ranges`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges), which includes a full explanation of ranges, including this detail:

> The `/` and `?` may be preceded with another address.  The search starts from there.

So if you have `5/foo/` it means the first line matching "foo" after line 5, or `'b/bar/` means the first line matching "bar" after mark `'b`.

So `:'a,'b/pattern/p` means print lines from mark `'a` to the first line matching `/pattern/` *after* mark `'b`.

Note how this is *very* different from `:'a,'bg/pattern/p`, where the `/pattern/` is not part of the range, but instead it's an argument to the `:g` command. The `:'a,'bg/pattern/p` command will print only lines *matching* `/pattern/` inside the range going from line where mark `'a` is, to the line where mark `'b` is (inclusive.)

Answer (score 1):

"Slash" is not a command for command-line mode. It's a line address. <strike>Hence `:'a,'b/pattern/` is the same as `:'a,/pattern/`</strike> That's why.

Comment: They're not quite equivalent... Address `'b/pattern/` in a range means the first line matching `/pattern/` *after* the `'b` mark.